# TCP client connection timesout from iPhone but works in Xcode simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, server, tcpclient

I have the server program running in one Linux virtual machine and client program running in Xcode in another virtual machine. The connection establishes successfully when run in a Xcode simulator but fails when deployed on device. My iPhone is not able to connect to the server from the app.

Comment: Mostly likely the iPhone is not on the same network as the server. Make sure that you're on WiFi and not cellular data.

Comment: I am on WiFi. I even tried to create a hotspot from windows so the device will be in same network.